# Add drawing functionality in type ui.Linker Map

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth, google-earth-api

is there drawing functionality in the ui.Linker Map object of Earth Engine?

```
var linker = ui.Map.Linker(maps)

function display3 ()   {
    var map = new ui.Map();
    map.addLayer(toFeature);
    map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');
    map.centerObject(prorestaura_mg, 9)
    map.addLayer(select_2016,visPar432, 'Com nuvem - 2016');
    map.addLayer(select_2016.mask(select_2016.select('BQA').eq(2720)),visMosaic, 'Sem nuvem -2016',false);
    map.addLayer(prorestaura_mg.draw({color: 'F8E9CA', pointRadius: 5}), {},'PRO-RESTAURA/MG',false);
    map.add(ui.Label('DATA:26-08-2016', {position:'bottom-center', fontWeight: 'bold'}))
    map.ui.enableDrawing(false)
    return map}    } });
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot include the drawing tools in a `ui.Map` instance. The only workaround I found is to get, at least, the only instance of the drawing map.

```js
// Get Drawing Map
var root_widgets = ui.root.widgets()
var drawing_map = root_widgets.get(0)
drawing_map.add(ui.Label('Drawing Map'))

var second_map = ui.Map()
second_map.add(ui.Label('NOT Drawing Map'))

ui.Map.Linker([drawing_map, second_map])

ui.root.clear()
ui.root.add(second_map)
ui.root.add(drawing_map)
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/e12c39b06be55a90ed0c7000803d42d1

Comment: Unfortunately, I can´t add theses lines of code in my code. 
Can you help to figure out how can I join your suggestion to mine?
 https://code.earthengine.google.com/a8a631b0643468e5a13688b05490049f

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/658df1623ac270307f8d5e224e08dce9

Comment: how did it go @LilianGuimarães?

Comment: This work amazing for me, Rodrigo, thank you verry much!

Comment: great! you're welcome =)